# Spring boot war cannot find index.html

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

Im a beginner in Spring boot and tomcat, and i get this issue:

When deploying a spring boot war file on a the tomcat server, i get a problem when i want to add a static index.html alongside with it as a war.

to enable it to be deployed as war i added this to my application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.app"})
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.app"})
public class MyApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyApp.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

now the application works, but the index.html (which is located under src/main/resources) won't show (im getting Whitelabel Error Page with "There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'GET' not supported")

but if i create it like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.app"})
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.app"})
public class MyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

it shows me the index.html (but the application won't work for a GET request from the browser which work earlier i get HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource is not available. ).

How can i configure it so they both will work?

this is my pom.xml

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <finalName>myapp</finalName>
</build>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which is located under src/main/resources

Add the `index.html` to `src/main/resources/public` directory

According to [spring boot's doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content):

> By default Spring Boot will serve static content from a directory
>   called /static (or /public or /resources or /META-INF/resources) in
>   the classpath or from the root of the ServletContext

Comment: it didn't worked.

i've tried to put the index.hml in this paths:

/src/main/resources/public/index.html
/src/main/resources/static/index.html
/src/main/resources/index.html
src/main/resources/META-INF/index.html

and it didn't worked, same Whitelabel Error Page.

(MyApp class is under src/main/java/com/app/main)

Comment: Did you add index.html to all of them? Whats the error?

Comment: yes, i've add it to all of them at once.
the error i get is:          


Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Jan 12 00:20:42 IST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'GET' not supported

Comment: to what url you send your requests? `/` or `index.html`?

Comment: Did you define a non `GET` controller method on `/`? if so, send your requests to `/index.html`

Comment: And adding `index.html` to just `public` directory would suffice

Comment: how about `/myapp` url?

Comment: you were right! i got a "non GET controller method on /" and when i changed it it works.
I appreciate your assist.

Comment: Do we need to define a controller method to get index.html